# Closing full screen JS menu on a one page website when menu links are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen, onepage-scroll

I am having a play with a menu idea. I have very little JS knowlege so I want to know if what i am trying to achieve is doable.

I have been playing with a multibox menu from codrops [this menu](https://tympanus.net/Development/MultiboxMenu/)

From the looks of it the menu is designed to link to external pages, what I am trying to do is link to sections within the same page as I would look to build a one page site, so what I need is the menu to close when one of the menu links are clicked, as currently it just stays open.

I have tried to use the same "class" function from the close button in the links but this for some reason makes the close button disappear, not an effective solution.

I have looked at similar questions posted and tried to fix with previous answers but I'm having no luck.

```html
<main>
   <div class="frame">
    <header class="codrops-header">
     <div class="codrops-links">
      <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon--prev" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLayoutScrollableContent/" title="Previous Demo"><svg class="icon icon--arrow"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg></a>
      <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon--drop" href="https://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=36043" title="Back to the article"><svg class="icon icon--drop"><use xlink:href="#icon-drop"></use></svg></a>
     </div>
     <h1 class="codrops-header__title">Multibox Menu</h1>
    </header>
    <p class="info">12 &mdash; 24 May 2019 &middot; Bannockburn &middot; Stirling &middot; UK</p>
    <a class="github" href="https://github.com/codrops/MultiboxMenu/" title="Find this project on GitHub"><svg class="icon icon--github"><use xlink:href="#icon-github"></use></svg></a>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url(img/1.jpg)"></div>
    <h2 class="content__title">Carmeca</h2>
    <p class="content__tagline">Europe's most immersive LARP experience</p>
   </div>
   <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item menu__item--1" data-direction="bt">
     <div class="menu__item-inner">
      <div class="mainmenu">
       <a href="#" class="mainmenu__item">Story</a>
       <a href="#" class="mainmenu__item">Chronicles</a>
       <a href="#" class="mainmenu__item">Tour</a>
       <a href="#" class="mainmenu__item">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <p class="label label--topleft label--vert-mirror">the important stuff</p>
      <p class="label label--bottomright label--vert">made in bannockburn</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item menu__item--2" data-direction="lr">
     <div class="menu__item-inner">
      <div class="menu__item-map"></div>
      <a href="#" class="menu__item-hoverlink">The location</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item menu__item--3" data-direction="bt">
     <div class="menu__item-inner">
      <div class="sidemenu">
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">The Gameplay</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">About LARP</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">The Rules</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">History</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">People</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">Join</span></a>
       <a href="#" class="sidemenu__item"><span class="sidemenu__item-inner">...</span></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item menu__item--4" data-direction="rl">
     <div class="menu__item-inner">
      <p class="label label--topleft label--line">Join us now</p>
      <a href="#" class="menu__item-link">Learn how to <br> participate</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item menu__item--5" data-direction="tb">
     <div class="menu__item-inner">
      <p class="quote">Hail to thee, our infantry, still brave, beyond the grave</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button class="action action--menu"><svg class="icon icon--menu"><use xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use></svg></button>
    <button class="action action--close"><svg class="icon icon--close"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg></button>
   </nav>
  </main>
```

```js
{
    // Class Menu.
    class Menu {
        constructor(el) {
            this.DOM = {el: el};
            // Open and close ctls.
            this.DOM.openCtrl = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.action--menu');
            this.DOM.closeCtrl = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.action--close');
            this.DOM.openCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
            this.DOM.closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
            this.DOM.openCtrl.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
                allowTilt = false;
                tilt.reset()
            });
            this.DOM.openCtrl.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                allowTilt = true;
            });

            // The menu items.
            this.DOM.items = Array.from(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.menu__item'));
            // The total number of items.
            this.itemsTotal = this.DOM.items.length;

            // Custom elements that will be animated.
            this.DOM.mainLinks = this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.mainmenu > a.mainmenu__item');
            this.DOM.sidemenuLinks = this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.sidemenu span.sidemenu__item-inner');
            this.DOM.menulink = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.menu__item-link');
        }
        // Open the menu.
        open() {
            this.toggle('open');
        }
        // Close the menu.
        close() {
            this.toggle('close');
        }
        toggle(action) {
            if ( this.isAnimating ) return;
            // (dis)allow the main image tilt effect.
            allowTilt = action === 'open' ? false : true;
            this.isAnimating = true;
            // Toggling the open state class.
            this.DOM.el.classList[action === 'open' ? 'add' : 'remove']('menu--open');
            // After all is animated..
            const animationEnd = (pos) => {
                if ( pos === this.itemsTotal-1 ) {
                    this.isAnimating = false;
                }
            };
```

I have tried to take this line of code and copy it from th JS file `this.DOM.closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());` and change the `closeCtrl` and replace it with `mainLinks` however that didnt work and to be totally honest I have absolutely no idea what i'm doing.

I would imagine it's a fairly straightforward fix for someone that understands JS. 
Hopefully you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which i'm sure can be improved, but however it does the job...

**HTML (add the item--close classes)**

```
<a href="#" class="mainmenu__item item--close1">Item1</a>
<a href="#" class="mainmenu__item item--close2">Item2</a>
<a href="#" class="mainmenu__item item--close3">Item3</a>
<a href="#" class="mainmenu__item item--close4">Item4</a>
<a href="#" class="mainmenu__item item--close5">Item5</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (add this code demo.js)**

```
// Open and close ctls.
this.DOM.openCtrl = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.action--menu');
this.DOM.closeCtrl = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.action--close');
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl1 = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.item--close1');
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl2 = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.item--close2');
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl3 = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.item--close3');
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl4 = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.item--close4');
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl5 = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.item--close5');

this.DOM.openCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
this.DOM.closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl1.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl2.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl3.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl4.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
this.DOM.ItemcloseCtrl5.addEventListener('click', () => this.close());
```